# Embedding tinyMCE in django flatpage

Tags: python, django, django-tinymce

I'm using [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce). I'd like to know how to embed it in a flatpage in admin panel.

From the project's readme:

Add tinymce to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py for your project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'tinymce',
)
```

Add tinymce.urls to urls.py for your project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
)
```

My flatpage url :

```
url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

Comment: Some code wouldn't hurt, it's hard to help you if you don't show us what you tried and were you got stuck...

Comment: I'm not clear on what "adding it on a flatpage in admin panel" means. Do you want to add tinyMCE on a page of the admin, as to edit some model's field? Or do you actually want to use it in a django flatpage somewhere else on your site?

Comment: use it with  django flatpage

Answer (score 13):

you need to override the widget for the content field. To do this:

1. extend the `FlatpageForm` ModelForm as `PageForm`
2. extend the `FlatPageAdmin` to use the new `PageForm`

code example:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatpageForm, FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
## OOPS this is a custom widget that works for initializing
## tinymce instances on stacked and tabular inlines
## for flatpages, just use the tinymce packaged one.
#from content.widgets import TinyMCE 
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


class PageForm(FlatpageForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
        widgets = {
            'content' : TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 15}),
        }


class PageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    """
    Page Admin
    """
    form = PageForm
```

then unregister the old flatpage admin and reregister the new one

```
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, PageAdmin)
```

Comment: I changed `from content.widgets import TinyMCE` to `from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE` The content app widget is a custom widget I use in my projects, just ignore it and use the tinymce packaged one

Comment: Where would the above file go? `project/project/admin.py`?

Comment: You can add it to any admin.py anywhere in your project - but i prefer to keep my code compartmentalized a little better than that. Create an app for overriding / extending flatpages. I call my app `content` then in my `content/admin.py`, I add the above code.

Comment: Awesome - I successfully got this working for [Django Pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown) (same editor that Stack Overflow uses) using the same method but registering the `AdminPagedownWidget` instead of the `TinyMCE` widget.

Comment: Used it with Ckeditor as @nhinkle has done with Django_Pagedown. I've just changed TinyMCE by : 
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget