# Use Django Flatpages with TinyMCE

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, django-flatpages, django-tinymce

I'm trying to achive the Django TinyMCE widget with Django Flatpages (into Admin).

I already read this [Embedding tinyMCE in django flatpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123927/embedding-tinymce-in-django-flatpage)

I did the sabe but is not working. Here is my admin.py code:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatpageForm, FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
from django.contrib import admin


class PageForm(FlatpageForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
        widgets = {
            'content': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 15}),
        }


class PageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    """
    Page Admin
    """
    form = PageForm

admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, PageAdmin)
```

My site is running well, without erros, is possible to edit or create a new Django Flatpage but the widget doesn't appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something different, and I was missing the "fields" property in meta Class, following the new code, tested and running:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatpageForm, FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


class FlatPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
        fields = '__all__'


class PageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    """
    Page Admin
    """
    form = FlatPageForm


admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, PageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me (Django 1.10) so this is what worked for me.

1. I first created a new app called content in my project to keep organized.

   ```
   manage.py startapp content
   ```
2. I added this to my admin.py

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin
   from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
   from django.db import models
   from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


   # Register your models here.
   class PageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
   """
   Page Admin
   """
   formfield_overrides = {
       models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 15})},
   }


   admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
   admin.site.register(FlatPage, PageAdmin)
   ```
3. Finally run `manage.py collectstatic`, restart your webserver and refresh.